# How to know if an object (die) is at rest in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have seen some old code using:

```
 if(rigidbody.IsSleeping()){
    //do something
 }
```

however with the newer Unity 5+ the `rigidybody` doesn't work anymore.  How is this accomplished now?

Comment: What do you mean the rigid body doesn't work anymore ? This.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().IsSleeping()

Comment: you very likely simply want to check if the velocity is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity 5 you need to use `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` in order to access a `Rigidbody` component on your GameObject.  So in your case you could say:

```
if(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().IsSleeping())
{
    //do something
}
```

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/23/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating/) which details this exact API change in Unity 5.